# YouTube Live Streaming API How to set custom thumbnails to Live Broadcast Object

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am creating YouTube live broadcasts using YouTube live streaming API (by using PHP API client library) everything is working fine my question is can we also set thumbnails to that broadcast object using API so that on events page or watch page it shows our custom image right now its shows channel default image? If yes then please let us know how we can achieve that.

I have noted we can change thumbnail through website but i want to change it using PHP API client.

Thanks,
Faraz

Comment: Have you tried checking the documentation?

Comment: @DaImTo I have checked the documentation no information provided how to set custom thumbnails while inserting or updating live broadcast object

Comment: Hello @DaImTo you have not replied on this yet please let us know how we can change thumbnail using php api client library for live broadcast